# Subsequence of one string but not of others

Tags: algorithms, regular-languages, strings, substrings, subsequences

Let $\Sigma$ be an alphabet, and let $x^+,x^-_1,\dots,x^-_n \in \Sigma^*$ be strings over that alphabet.  Call a string $s \in \Sigma^*$ *good* if $s$ is a subsequence of $x^+$ but not a subsequence of any of $x^-_1,\dots,x^-_n$.

Given $x^+,x^-_1,\dots,x^-_n$, I am looking to find the shortest good string $s$.  Is there a reasonable algorithm for this?  I am interested in a practical algorithm, even if its worst-case running time is not great.  In my domain, the strings $x^+,x^-_1,\dots,x^-_n$ might be fairly long but I expect there will exist a good string $s$ that is fairly short, in case that helps.

The case $n=1$ is handled by [Shortest sub-sequence of one string, that's not a sub-sequence of another string](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12037/755), but I need to deal with the case $n>1$.

Comment: My standard proposal: suffix tree? The string you're looking for is the node with smallest level among all that have only $(x^+, \_)$ as leaf. Oh, wait... sub*sequence*? Damn. Hm.

Comment: Is this problem without $x^+$ the dual to longest common subsequence? If so, maybe something can be done along those lines. (Enumerating common non-subsequences by increasing length would solve your problem.)

Comment: I believe that Aryabhata's DP can be extended fairly easily to the $n > 1$ case: just use $n$ tables, one for each $x_i^-$, and then hunt for the smallest $L$ such that **for each table $i$**, and for some $k$, $is\_there[i, k, t, L] = false$.  That will tell you the length ($L$) and the final character ($x^+[k]$), but I'm not yet sure how to extract the earlier characters...

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I don't think that works.  That might pick one subsequence of $x^+$ of length $L$ that isn't a subsequence of $x^-_1$, and a different subsequence of $x^+$ of length $L$ that isn't a subsequence of $x^-_2$.  (The first one might be a subsequence of $x^-_2$, and the second one a subsequence of $x^-_1$, which would be bad.)  We need a single subsequence of $x^+$, not a separate one for each $x^-_i$.  Or did I miss something clever about your idea?

Comment: @Raphael, that sounds right to me, so maybe that can lead somewhere.  Unfortunately the basic dynamic programming algorithm for longest common subsequence of $n$ sequence takes time exponential in $n$ (time proportional to $\ell^n$, where $\ell$ is the length of the $x$'s).  Do you know of improvements to the basic dynamic programming algorithm that would reduce this?

Comment: @D.W.: You're right, and I think this explains why I couldn't figure out how to backtrace the DP matrix to find the rest of the solution -- because there might not be any "the solution", just several different ones!  (Of the same length and ending with the same character, but otherwise different.)

Comment: If you don't need absolutely the shortest subsequence, you could use the fact that, if a string $s$ is not a subsequence of any $x_i^-$, then it is also not a subsequence of any *interleaving* of the strings $x_i^-$.  So you could try many different ways of randomly interleaving the $n$ strings $x_i^-$ into a single string, and for each such interleaving $y_j$, look for a subsequence $z_j$ of $x^+$ that avoids being a subsequence of $y_j$ using Aryabhata's DP, and pick whichever $z_j$ is shortest.

Comment: @D.W. Not off the top of my head, no. :/ But I guess there's at least literature on LCSS? If the problems are indeed dual, it's unlikely that yours is any easier...

Comment: <random thought>We are looking for strings of length k that have edit distance (modified so that insertions are free) of 0 with $x^+$ and >0 with all the $x^-$.</random thought>

Comment: @j_random_hacker, that's clever -- I like that!  Thank you.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Add an answer? Your algorithm is one you can let run, keeping track of solution quality. Aborting after no improvement has been made for $k$ iterations should yield reasonable solutions. (Somehow, this now makes me think of genetic algorithms; maybe worth a try?)

Answer (score 1):

### Mistakes

First of all, in the comments I made a few mistakes: Both the original claim I made about interleaving, and the comment "correcting" it (now deleted) were wrong, and separately my claim that trying all possible interleavings must yield an optimal solution was also wrong (I give a simple counterexample below).  Finally, my suggestion to set $x^+ = z_j$ and iterate, or use beam search, is actually also not helpful: Whatever answer could be produced by doing this and applying Aryabhata's DP can never be better than using the original $x^+$, since all it does is reduce the size of the solution set from which the DP can pick.  Sorry!  Hopefully the improved version below contains no further problems...

I also noticed two mistakes in [Aryabhata's DP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/12037/shortest-sub-sequence-of-one-string-thats-not-a-sub-sequence-of-another-string) as well.  Fortunately they can both be easily repaired (see my comments on that post).

### A heuristic solution using random interleavings

If you don't need absolutely the shortest subsequence, you could use the fact that, if a string $s$ is a subsequence of some $x^-_i$, then it is also a subsequence of every possible *interleaving* of all the strings $x^-_i$.  Turning this around, if $s$ is not a subsequence of some particular interleaving of all the strings $x^-_i$, then it is not a subsequence of *any* individual $x^-_i$.

So you could try many different ways of randomly interleaving the $n$ strings $x^−_i$ into a single string, and for each such interleaving $y_j$, look for the shortest subsequence $z_j$ of $x^+$ that avoids being a subsequence of $y_j$ using [Aryabhata's nice DP algorithm for the two-string case](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/12038/1984), and pick whichever $z_j$ is shortest over all interleavings you tried.

### Caveat: No guarantee of optimality even if we try all interleavings

Surprisingly (to me at least), even if you repeat the above procedure for all possible interleavings, you are not guaranteed to find the optimal solution: Consider the instance in which $x^+ = aaa$, $n=2$, and $x^-_1 = x^-_2 = a$.  Then $aa$ is an optimal solution with length 2, but the shortest solution found by trying all interleavings of $x^-_1$ and $x^-_2$ is $aaa$, with length 3.